# problema con un pdf en iframe, el boton de descargar no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

estoy desde hace unos dias con este problema, en mi página web cree un boton para que este abriera un pdf en iframe en otra pagina, pero el problema recide en que una vez que se abre la página no termina de cargar y lo segundo es que el boton de descargar el pdf no funciona en chrome pero si en firefox ...
este es mi codigo :

```
 function debugBase64(base64URL)
       {
                var win = window.open();
                win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                win.window.focus();
            }
```

y luego el boton para mostrar:

```
$(".icon-export-alt").click(function()
{
     console.log("click reporte");
     debugBase64("data:application/pdf;base64, " + pdf1);
});
```

el archivo que quiero mostrar esta en base64 y lo tengo en una variable que es pdf1, por favor si podrian decirme que es lo que me falta o esta pasando sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: pudiste resolver este problema? Me esta pasando lo mismo, muestra bien el pdf en una nueva pestaña pero no me permite descargarlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Es la misma función que el auto tiene pero corregida, abrir en una nueva pestaña el PDF en base64, sin estar corregida abre una pestaña en blanco:

```
function debugBase64(base64URL){
     var win = window.open("")
     win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas recientemente me tope con el mismo problema desconozco la razón pero si se visualiza el pdf en una nueva pestaña NO permite descargarlo sin embargo el iframe dentro de la misma pestaña de mi pagina o en una pestaña emergente SI permite descargar el documento espero sirva saludos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<v-dialog v-model="pdfVer" width="800">
   <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="fondoAzulLetraBlanca">
         PDF
      </v-card-title>

     <v-card-text>
       <iframe :src="srcPDF" id="pdfVer" height="1000px" width="100%"></iframe>
     </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: En este caso, el atributo iframe permite añadir una propiedad `allow-downloads` y podría ayudarte a resolver eso. Más información [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#browser_compatibility)